# HTML CSS image positioning

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to understand the CSS and HTML to position a logo  on my webpage. I purchased a holding page template and I'm trying to move the logo to be placed in the middle, below the 12. I've tried numerous attempts at different variations using *position* and *text-align* in the CSS, as well as adjusting the *left* and *top* fields. In the end I've just confused myself even further.

Here's a snippet of the HTML (there are the closing 's and 's and the css

```css
#time-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
.clock-label {
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
#imgLogo {
  position: absolute;
}
#imgLogo .img {
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<section class="mainarea">
  <div class="active" id="clock">
    <div class="clock-container">
      <div id="time-container-wrap">
        <div id="time-container">
          <div class="numbers-container"></div>
          <span class="clock-label" style="width: 130px; height: 88px; display:block" id="imgLogo"><img src="img/CroftLogo11.png" style="width: 130px; height: 88px;"/></span>
```

Here's a link to the website, in case it is easier to use the developer tools to understand my issue better - [www.croftwatches.com](http://www.croftwatches.com)

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your snippet to provide the HTML (including the closing tags) and the CSS together in the same snippet (and remove whichever of the two becomes surplus to requirements). Provide the *minimal* necessary ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)) code (HTML/CSS) to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hi David, Many thanks for your feedback, I've never dived into the world of HTML/CSS before, so your MVCE link was very useful.

Answer (score 2):

```
.clock-label {
  width: 100%;
  height: 88px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

That should center your logo.

Answer (score 1):

Bioto successfully centered your logo, but you would also need to move it down to be under the 12 as explained in your question. To do so you can simply add a top margin of roughly 100px;

```
width: 100%;
height: 88px;
display: block;
margin-top: 100px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of your `#time-container` to the width of your image (the `margin: 0 auto;` does the vertical alignment for you.

If you alter the `0`, you can add an space to the top of the page.

```css
#time-container {
  width: 130px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
.clock-label {
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
#imgLogo {
  position: absolute;
}
#imgLogo .img {
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<section class="mainarea">
  <div class="active" id="clock">
    <div class="clock-container">
      <div id="time-container-wrap">
        <div id="time-container">
          <div class="numbers-container"></div>
          <span class="clock-label" style="width: 130px; height: 88px; display:block" id="imgLogo"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/130/88/abstract" style="width: 130px; height: 88px;"/></span>
```